# Adjust image size according to screen resolution

Tags: css, image, magento-1.8

I have an image in my footer with `width:1363px` and `height: 100px`. This looks fine on my desktop computer with resolution 1366*768 but when I check the site with resolution 1024*768 the size of the image is not shrinking.

So my question is how do I adjust the size of the image according to screen size using css. I used media queries and changed the width and height of image but it still remains the same. I also tried some other tricks with no luck.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply set the image to `width: 100%` and it will scale with the browser.

### [Demo JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dm28M/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="footer">
    <img src="~/yourimage.jpg" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#footer img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Without seeing your image, it's difficult to advise, but an alternative is to not use a full width image and use a background colour instead:

### [Demo JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dm28M/2/)

Or use a horizontally repeating image:

### [Demo JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dm28M/3/)

Comment: sorry for late reply. This solved the issue for my footer,Thanks a lot .one more question i have an image  which i have made to repeat at different places in my home page and i used the same trick but for this image it doesn't work i do know why can u give any suggestions.

Comment: If you have a new question, please post it as a new question with additional details. If you send the link to me in comments here I will be notified when you've sent it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use css bootstrap responsive for this. 
http://getbootstrap.com/css/

It shrinks the contents of your div according to screen size.

But if you want to do it manually, set width of footer content to (example)

```
width:100%
```

Then set a specific size for footer (example)

```
width:1024px
```

After that use @media queries
http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Example

```
@media all and (max-width: 1024px) and (min-width: 768px){
  #footer{
   width:800px; //or something like this
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
img{width: 100%; max-width: 1363px;}
```

This should shrink the image down with the size of the browser, but won't distort the image on resolutions higher than it's maximum width.

Answer (score 0):

you put that image in container tag and after that give a width t0 that image and make height auto of that image.